# EF 5 DBContext.Set<T>.Remove(entity) fails, but succeeds when I debug and step into

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Got a very strange scenario here.

Calling the following Code using DBContext the Remove Fails

```
int id = 5;
var sql = "SELECT * from dbo.Product WHERE productId = @id";
var data = dbContext.Set<Product>().SqlQuery(sql, new object[] {new SQLParameter("id", id)});

var entityToDelete = data.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();

dbContext.Set<Product>().Remove(entityToDelete); 
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I receive the following Error Message:

> Entities in 'MyEntities.Products' participate in the
>   'FK_Product_ProductType' relationship. 0 related 'ProductType' were
>   found. 1 'ProductType' is expected.

Now Every product has a foreign key reference to a ProductType.  There is actually a value set for this Foreign Key in the Database.

Here is the kicker.  When I debug and step into the code line by line it succeeds?  Very strange?  Why is this happening?  any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It succeeds when I watch the variable entityToDelete when Debugging.  But fails if I remove the watch.  Which makes me think it has something to do with Lazy Loading.

Comment: Probably a side effect of lazy loading and watch/auto/local debug window. Why don't you use linq query instead of a sql query i.e. data.Products.Where(p => p.Id == 5). Does it help?

Comment: @Pawel   Not using a LINQ query because this is actually a Generic Method  `public void Delete<T>(Int64 id)`   Our naming convention in the DB for Primary keys is [TableName] id because of this I need to dynamically generate the Query.

Comment: I see. Can you hardcode to check if linq query does the trick?

Comment: @Pawel  Already did that and yes it does the trick.

Comment: Try to set the SqlQuery as [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbsqlquery.asnotracking(v=vs.103).aspx). Like `SqlQuery(sql, new object[] {new SQLParameter("id", id)}).AsNoTracking();`

Comment: @jehof  Tried that but no luck

Comment: @JohnHartsock - I believe that if you use SqlQuery there is no magic around relationships happening what causes the issues you have. I think instead of using SQL query you could generate an expression tree dynamically or (if you realy brave) you could use ESql

Comment: @Pawel.... your suggestion was right on.  Using ESQL worked perfectly.